# Python Excel file to Dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, pyqt

I would like to create depandant combobox from the Excel file. If the combo1 is selected, the combo2 will be changed depending on Combo1. The input is as below.

| City | Name |
| --- | --- |
| AA | John |
| AA | Anne |
| BB | Sean |
| BB | Dylan |

I have tried to create Pandas dataframe and use to_dict(). But it was not the result I expect.

The expected result
{"AA": [["John"], ["Anne"]], "BB": [["Sean"], ["Dylan"]]}.

Thank you.

Edit : Code I have tried. If combo1 "AA" is selected, combo2 will display "John","Anne"

```
df = (pd.read_excel("test.xls"))

#due to I don't need the "City" && "Name".
df.set_index('City')['Name'].to_dict()
```

Output :
`{'AA': 'Anne', 'BB': 'Dylan'}`

```
df.to_dict("r")
```

Output :
`[{'City': 'AA', 'Name': 'John'}, {'City': 'AA', 'Name': 'Anne'}, {'City': 'BB', 'Name': 'Sean'}, {'City': 'BB', 'Name': 'Dylan'}]`

```
df.to_dict("list")
```

Output :
`{'City': ['AA', 'AA', 'BB', 'BB'], 'Name': ['John', 'Anne', 'Sean', 'Dylan']}`

Comment: Kindly provide the code that you have tried as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try via `groupby()`,`agg()` and `to_dict()` method:

```
out=df.groupby('City')['Name'].agg(list).to_dict()
#you can also use apply() in place of agg() method
```

output of `out`:

```
{'AA': ['John', 'Anne'], 'BB': ['Sean', 'Dylan']}
```